# How to convert selected text to Hyperlink?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I want to convert the selected text from Edit Text to Hyperlink. Basically i know how to convert text in hyperlink, but not able to do in Edit Text.

I have tried **Linkify**, but not working.

Any Help would be appreciated..

Comment: Show us how you used Linkify. Post the code here.

Comment: Linkify.add(text,Linkify.WEB_URLS);

Comment: And how did you use that in your EditText ?!!

Comment: I am selecting the text using SelectionStart and SelectionEnd and then making substring of selected text , storing text back to edit text

Comment: From what I read, it seems that Linkify is designed to work with TextView but not EditText. So, Linkify is a dead-end. Sorry

Comment: What about using [`esitText.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29)? This will convert any hyperlink in your EditText.

Comment: Maybe explaining what you are trying to achieve in the end would be better.

Comment: @iturki AutoLinkMask is found to be useful,but how to convert only selected text, your code will convert the whole text if links found. I need to make it with selection..

Comment: @Agrawal I'm afraid that you can't achieve that. I suggest you try a different approach. Like copying the selected text to a TextView where it is clickable.

Comment: @iturki I have achieved using SpannableStringBuilder and autolinkMask. Somehow your also code helped me . Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way how i solved the problem.

text = EditText

```
            int start = text.getSelectionStart();

            int end = text.getSelectionEnd();

            SpannableStringBuilder spb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text
                    .getText().toString());

            String hyper = text.getText().toString().substring(start, end);

            text.setText(hyper);

            text.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL); // Linkify.WEB_URLS

            text.setText(spb);
```